# Read json object

Tags: javascript, php, json, jquery

I'm having a problem reading JSON; my PHP server encodes an object created with the stdClass, then sends this object on my Ajax asynchronous script. I tried to alert the object and the
representation is like this:

```
alert(prova) //Gives {"idProva":"3","name":"test"}
```

Now if the variable name is `prova`, how can I read the value 3?

I tried using `prova.idProva`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The reference to `prova.idProva` should definitely work. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/SpSms/ -- Show your code, I have a feeling you're trying to work outside the callback, thus alerting `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ajax all add `dataType:'json'`

```
$.ajax({url: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (prova) {
        alert(prova.idProva);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

try parsing json into a object

```
var json = '{"idProva":"3","name":"test"}',
obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj.idProva);
```

i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,

```
var data = {"idProva":"3","name":"test"}
console.log(data['idProva']);
```